# Custom XmlSerializer for some types not working in ASP.NET Web API 2.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

ASP.NET Web API does not invoke the **XmlSerializer** registered for **MyType** as below -

When i place breakpoints in either of the MySerializer method it does not heat.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;    
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.RemoveSerializer(typeof(MyType));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<MyType>(new MySerializer());
```

MySerializer is implemented as below -

```
 public class MySerializer : System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
        {
            public override bool CanDeserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader)
            {
                return base.CanDeserialize(xmlReader);
            }
            protected override System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader CreateReader()
            {
                return base.CreateReader();
            }

            protected override System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter CreateWriter()
            {
                return base.CreateWriter();
            }

            protected override object Deserialize(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader)
            {
                return base.Deserialize(reader);
            }


            protected override void Serialize(object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter writer)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.Serialize(o, writer);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am unable to repro your issue

Comment: Thanks Kiran, I will retry this from one Web API application. Not sure why it is not working in my app.

Comment: @kiran-challa, sorry for late response. i tried to verify above apart for new app, but it is still now working. Am I missing anything here?